# How to take a full page screenshot of a given URL?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of an entire website (not just the visible part in the browser when opening it). I searched for solutions and found many answers, none of which seem to work for me.

My current approach works for some websites:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def createPNGChrome(url):
    DRIVER = '/Users/userName/PycharmProjects/WebsiteMonitor/Screenshots/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)

    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

    screenshot = element.screenshot_as_png
    driver.quit()

    return screenshot

# works
#fullPageScreenshot = createPNGChrome('https://news.ycombinator.com/')

# works
#fullPageScreenshot = createPNGChrome('https://www.spotify.com/de/')

# fails
fullPageScreenshot = createPNGChrome('https://www.de.abbott/media-center/press-releases/05-10-2018.html')  # fails

with open('fullPageScreenshot.png', "wb") as file:
    file.write(fullPageScreenshot)
```

For the last website (abbott) I get the following exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot take screenshot with 0 height."}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.5 x86_64)
```

Is there a reliable fix for this approach? I'm also fine with completely different solutions that don't use selenium as long as the results are reliable full-page screenshots.

Comment: there's an overlay there: <div class="corpnews-media-overlay"> with zero height.  Might be causing the issue.

Comment: maybe try it on the driver... don't bother with body element.... driver.screenshot_as_png

Comment: @pcalkins calling it on the driver doesn't take a full page screenshot but only the currently visible part of the website in the browser window.

Comment: ok, this behavior must have changed at some point.  Use IEDriver instead.  (Using the IEDriver driver.screenshot is full page.)

Comment: could be it always worked like that but I never noticed it only took the full shot in IE.

Comment: @pcalkins Huh, with what version of IEDriver did you manage to take full-page screenshots? Both chrome and firefox (geckodriver) take only visible-part screenshots.

Comment: v 3.3.0 of IEDriver... it's also packaged with the Browsermator:  https://www.browsermator.com

Comment: if you don't want to use IEDriver, you could also try executing a javascript which removes that 0 height overlay div.  (but again I'm not positive that's causing the issue here).  I did test capturing that page in IEDriver and it worked just fine.